# File routes for images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get an image saved on my computer and set it as a background image covering the whole page using CSS. Please help.

The html code is this:

```
<div class="page-container">
<h1>HI</h1>
</div>
```

The CSS code is this:

```
.page-container {background-image: url(css/images/huelvapiersunset.jpg);
height: 100%;
}
```

The files are organised like this:

imagetest/css/images

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code here not image

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please paste actual code into your question in the form of a [mcve] and not pictures of code and also please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Try `background-image: url('./css/images/huelvapiersunset.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

In order that the image appear as background with the provided setting two main changes have to be made in `styles.css`.
1. The url in the background-image to become `url('images/huelvapiersunset.jpg')`. Here the quotes, `'`, were added add the `css` was removed since this file is already in the `css` folder.
2. The height to become equal to the height of the used image in pixels.
Below is the code of a working example.

```
.page-container {
  background-image: url('images/huelvapiersunset.jpg');
  height: 1167px;
}
```

And the appearing [background image with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0kms.png).